# How to prevent SQL injection attack when a sql query is passed in from the UI

Tags: sql, jdbc, sql-injection

I have a Java application that does a POST with the sql query that is typed in the UI and is executed using JDBC. Since the query is user defined, I'm unable to find a way to prevent the SQL injection issue. For instance if this is the query the user issues :

```
select * from test_table where id=123
```

a POST is done with this string to the servlet and this is executed as a query. Is there anyway to get around this since there is no restriction on what user can send in?

Thanks

Comment: It would be better to design the application so users are not typing queries in.

Comment: You could have such users use an application user Id w/only select access. to the database.  That way if anything but a select is attempted it fails.  The rest of the application could have Insert/update/delete access; but the connection this portion users is READ only;  but that doesn't stop them from reading any table they have select to.

Comment: lol this doesn't really qualify as SQL injection attack...you are going with SQL injection as a manner of operating.  Security here = trust your users.

Answer (score 1):

Technically if the user is allowed to write the entire query, it's not an injection attack risk, it's simply an attack risk

Run the query using a database user that has permission only to carry out the types of operations you deem acceptable on the tables you're willing to give access to.

For example, only permit SELECT on tableX, tableY and tableZ. No DML, no DDL and no selecting from any other table

If your dbms of choice doesn't allow fine grained control in this way then instead execute a regular batch script that creates another database containing only a few tables. Permit your users to query this new db. If it does get wrecked it will soon be dropped and replaced by a working one with updated data, by the script. This is also beneficial if placed on another server, it stops your live system from being innocently DOSed by a user executing a duff query that takes up all resource on the server

Comment: Furthering on what @Caius Jard said, depending on the DBMS, you can restrict access to specific schemas, stored procedures, and views, in which you can grant access to certain objects that have restricted fields that you may not want a user to be able to query (social security numbers, credit card info etc)

Answer (score 0):

SQL injection would be passing `select * from test_table where id=123` in place of a parameter.

Not sure exactly what information you are letting the application use, but I would suggest granting access only to a specific schema.  That would provide a consistent security model.

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, this is not SQL injection - I call this a "designed in" SQL injection.  How you deal with it depends on the use case:

- Design a separate interface that does not require the full SQL statement
- As Caius suggested, if you can limit the privs in the DB account to only do what the user can do, that would limit the damage
- If this is an administrative interface, you may want to limit the usage of this interface to "trusted" users.  If you go that route, you want to be very careful to document that users with this privilege have full access to the database, and provide an auditing mechanism to make sure that that list of users is well known.

It is not realistically possible to limit the SQL statement through validation - its a powerful language, especially in the context of modern databases.

See also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45989603/custom-sql-column-formulas-without-dynamic-sql)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway to get around this since there is no restriction on what user can send in?

I'm not sure what you mean by "get around." Is it not the design of this application to allow users to run any query?

If you want to prevent them from running unauthorized queries, then you'll have to implement some Java code in the servlet to check the query and decide whether it's one they're authorized to run.

Some people do this by whitelisting a specific set of known queries. Just match the user's input query against the whitelist.

If they can run a given query with a variety of different constant values, then replace constant values with a `?` in both the whitelisted form and in a copy of the user's input SQL query.

If they can run a variety of different queries, like with optional clauses and stuff, so that it's impossible to make a whitelist of finite length, then you'll have to implement a SQL parser in your Java servlet and some kind of business rule engine to decide if their query is authorized before you run it against the real database.

At this point, it seems easier to change the application front-end so that users are not allowed to submit arbitrary SQL queries!